# How to recognize when tf has stopped publishing?

Tags: ros, topic, publish, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use /tf topic to calculate a parameter with C++. I use what is written in the tf tutorial to listen to the transforms. I use a callback with "ros::spinOnce(); rate.sleep();" so only when I press Ctrl+C the program stops.
My problem is that I need to know when I do not have publishing tf; that means when the /tf stops publishing. Is there any function that checks the existence of /tf and for example becomes False when the /tf is not published anymore?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38696/how-to-recognize-when-tf-has-stopped-publishing?/) by [Antares](https://answers.ros.org/users/2375/antares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Antares](https://answers.ros.org/users/2375/antares/) on 2012-07-17**:
Thanks really cagatay it is working!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

you may check out waitForTransform()

```
bool tf::TransformListener::waitForTransform (const std::string &target_frame, const std::string &source_frame, const ros::Time &time, const ros::Duration &timeout, const ros::Duration &polling_sleep_duration=ros::Duration(0.01), std::string *error_msg=NULL) const
```

Test if source_frame can be transformed to target_frame at time time.
The waitForTransform() methods return a bool whether the transform can be evaluated. It will sleep and retry every polling_duration until the duration of timeout has been passed. It will not throw. If you pass a non NULL string pointer it will fill the string error_msg in the case of an error. (Note: That this takes notably more resources to generate the error message.)

or

The canTransform() methods return a bool whether the transform can be evaluated. It will not throw. If you pass a non NULL string pointer it will fill the string error_msg in the case of an error.

```
bool tf::TransformListener::canTransform (const std::string &target_frame, const std::string &source_frame, const ros::Time &time, std::string *error_msg=NULL) const
```

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4